# Prevent view of individual file in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm currently looking to host an app with the Angular frontend in a AWS S3 bucket connecting to a PHP backend using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've got it set up and it's working nicely.

However, using S3 to create a static website, anyone can view your code, including the various Angular JS files.  This is mostly fine, but I want to create either a file or folder to keep sensitive information in that cannot be viewed by anyone, but can be included/required by all other files.  Essentially I want a key that I can attach to all calls to the backend to make sure only authorised requests get through.

I've experimented with various permissions but always seems to be able to view all files, presumably because the static website hosting bucket policy ensures everything is public.

Any suggestions appreciated! 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of static website hosting on S3 means the content to be public, for example, you have maintenance of your app/web, so you redirect users to the S3 static page notifying there is maintenance ongoing. 
I am not sure what all have you tried when you refer to "experimented with various permissions", however, have you tried to setup a bucket policy or maybe setup the bucket as a CloudFront origin and set a Signed URL. This might be a bit tricky considering you want to call these sensitive files by other files. But the way to hide those sensitive files will either be by using some sort of bucket policy or by restricting using some sort of signed URL in my opinion.